# .on eventlistener works for firefox but not on IE or chrome

Tags: javascript, css, html, firefox, cross-browser

Let me get straight to this, I have a bunch of controls in html ,they are:

```js
var vup = 'mouseup';

$(document.body).on(vup, '.control_but', function(e)
{
    console.log(e.currentTarget.id);
    switch(e.currentTarget.id)
    {

        case 'pause_but':

            uiObj['player'].performAction('pause');
            break;
        case 'play_but':

            uiObj['player'].performAction('play');
            break;  
        case 'prev_but':

            uiObj['player'].performAction('previous');
            break;
        case 'next_but':
            uiObj['player'].performAction('next');
            break;
        case 'repeat_but':
        case 'repeatAll_but':
            uiObj['player'].performAction('repeat');
            break;
        case 'shuffle_but':
            uiObj['player'].performAction('shuffle');
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="controls_div">
            <img id="prev_but" class="control_but" src="media/prev.svg" alt="previous">
            <img id="play_but" class="control_but" src="media/play.svg" alt="play">
            <img id="pause_but" class="control_but hide" src="media/pause.svg" alt="play">
            <img id="next_but" class="control_but" src="media/next.svg" alt="next">
            <img id="repeat_but" class="control_but" src="media/repeat.svg" alt="repeat">
            <img id="repeatAll_but" class="control_but hide active_but" src="media/repeatAll.svg" alt="repeatAll">
            <img id="shuffle_but" class="control_but" src="media/shuffle.svg" alt="shuffle">
        </div>
```

I have assigned them mouseup event listener like this:

```
var vup = 'mouseup';
```

This works perfectly in mozilla firefox, but doesn't seem to work on chrome or IE. I don't seem to know why.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have edited your question to include a snippet. When I run the snippet in Chrome or IE, the event fires but `uiObj` is undefined?

Comment: Its a object array which I get it seperate file , showing the entire code would make things seems complicated than they are,so I only showed the part which I thought was relevant .

Also I run in the code locally but I still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

try with :

```
var vup = 'mouseup';
    $(document).on(vup, '.control_but', function(e)
    {
    // rest of your code...

    });
```

```js
     var vup = 'mouseup';

$(document).on(vup, '.control_but', function(e)
{
    console.log(e.currentTarget.id);
    switch(e.currentTarget.id)
    {

        case 'pause_but':
alert('pause_but');// only to show you
            uiObj['player'].performAction('pause');
            break;
        case 'play_but':
 alert('play_but');// only to show you
            uiObj['player'].performAction('play');
            break;  
        case 'prev_but':
alert('prev_but');// only to show you
            uiObj['player'].performAction('previous');
            break;
        case 'next_but':
            uiObj['player'].performAction('next');
            break;
        case 'repeat_but':
        case 'repeatAll_but':
            uiObj['player'].performAction('repeat');
            break;
        case 'shuffle_but':
            uiObj['player'].performAction('shuffle');
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="controls_div">
            <img id="prev_but" class="control_but" src="media/prev.svg" alt="previous">
            <img id="play_but" class="control_but" src="media/play.svg" alt="play">
            <img id="pause_but" class="control_but hide" src="media/pause.svg" alt="play">
            <img id="next_but" class="control_but" src="media/next.svg" alt="next">
            <img id="repeat_but" class="control_but" src="media/repeat.svg" alt="repeat">
            <img id="repeatAll_but" class="control_but hide active_but" src="media/repeatAll.svg" alt="repeatAll">
            <img id="shuffle_but" class="control_but" src="media/shuffle.svg" alt="shuffle">
        </div>
```

Comment: It doesn't in my case ,the thing is in the actual document the variables are defined in a different javascript file,maybe that's why, but the thing what I don't understand is why does it run on Firefox then

Answer (score 0):

Hello guys I found the solution

Seems like the place holder i.e variable name vup is not read as mouseup in chrome and IE. I don't exactly know why but when I change the event listerner to

```
   $(document).on('mouseup', '.control_but', function(e)
    {
    // rest of your code...

    });
```

It seems to work.

Thanks